# Passing Object from Table View Cell to Another View Controller Via Segue

Tags: swift, uitableview, object, segue

I have the following portion of my code that I'm trying to work out in order to move from a table view controller to a view controller.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
   let donation = donations[indexPath.row]
   print(donation)
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDonationReviewForm", sender: Any?)
}
```

On the above, when I print `donation`, it correctly prints the object and it's related fields. I know at some point I would need to use `override func prepare(for segue...` but I don't know how I am passing along the donation object to the next controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDonationReviewForm", sender:donations[indexPath.row])
```

---

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDonationReviewForm" {
        if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? NextViewController {
            nextViewController.toSend =  sender as! Donation 
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class NextViewController :UIViewController {
   var toSend:Donation?
   ....
}
```

Assuming `donations` is an array of `Donation` model